# Almost everywhere convergence of functions which verify a property on the set $C_b$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $T>0$. Let $(h_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq L^\infty([0, T])$ and $h\in L^\infty([0, T])$. Suppose that for all continuous and bounded functions $f:[0, T]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^Tf(t)h_n(t)dt = \int_0^Tf(t)h(t)dt.$$
Do we have that $(h_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $h$, $t$-almost everywhere?

Comment: The sequence $h_n(t) = \sin(n\pi t/T)$ is a counter-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is  well known example of a sequence $(h_n)$ such that $0 \leq h_n \leq 1$, $h_n \to h$ in measure but does not converge at any point. For this sequence your hypothesis is satisfied. [ There is a version of DCT with a.e. convergence replaced by convergence in measure].